# Как напечатать отрицательное число через printf?

Tags: ассемблер, masm

printf не печатает отрицательные числа. См. пример:

```
    .model flat
includelib msvcrt.lib
printf proto c, :vararg

    .data
resp db 'k = %d',10,13,0
k   db ?   

    .code
public main
main proc
    mov k, -1
    invoke printf, addr resp, k

    xor eax, eax
    ret
main endp
end
```

Получается k = 255, а не k = -1
Как напечатать отрицательное число?

---

Пока сделал так:

```
movsx ebx, k
invoke printf, addr resp, ebx
```

Comment: Попробуйте `k dd ?` вместо `db`. `printf` предполагает, что ему передают целые 32-битные числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите напечатать байт, используйте `"%hd"`,
`h` говорит что размер параметра - это байт.